# How do I view the test going on in Unity Playmode?

Tags: unity, camera, scene, testing

I'm working on a new project using TDD, and I'm doing a good job of checking everything from the ground up including checking physics interactions on instantiated prefab, but I've gotten about to the point I can get without actually seeing what's going on.

I've loaded the scene. I've instantiated a prefab. I've even instantiated a camera and called `.Render()` on it. How do I actually view my tests as they unfold?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Game window. It should be next to Scene. If you want to look at the values too, you can view them through the Inspector.